# Cometd point to point

Tags: java, cometd

I am very new to cometd in java.
I am interested more about cometd in java but when i googled it i barely find one link 
which is the cometd link and which is not clear in documentation.
Can some one post an example or a link which has a working example of publish subscribe and point to point?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [RESTful Web Services and Comet article](http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/cometslideshow.html)?

It has screenshots, step-by-step instructions, etc.  The Glassfish Developer's Guide also has [a nice article](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4496/ggrgt?a=view), with a downloadable WAR.

More:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/07/01/comet-slideshow-example-grizzly
- https://atmosphere.dev.java.net/
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/JEE6Samples